# I cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') this error came all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I'm trying to code a discord bot in js to code a bot for school project.
But when I play my code it write that error. I don't understand how it happens. And i didn't had that error few times ago.It may be because I changed a command (SlashCommandBuilder), but i don't really understand.
Can u  help me fix it pls? :)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { GiveawaysManager } = require('discord-giveaways');
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    ]
});

const prefix = "botto ";
const data1 = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("ping un utilisateur")
    .addUserOption(option => option
        .setName("utilisateur")
        .setDescription("utilisateur a ping")
        .setRequired(false));
const data2 = new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("clear")
        .setDescription("delete un message")
        .addIntegerOption(option => option
                .setName("number")
                .setDescription("nombre de message a clear")
                .setRequired(true)
        );
const dataGiveaway = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("giveaway")
    .setDescription("lancer un giveaway")
    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("duration")
        .setDescription("Duration of the giveaway in d/days(jour) + hrs/h(heure) + m(minute) + s(second) or time in ms")
        .setRequired(true)
        )
    .addIntegerOption(option => option
        .setName("winners")
        .setDescription("nombre de winners")
        .setRequired(true)
        )
    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("prize")
        .setDescription("prix du giveaway")
        .setRequired(true)
        );
const giveawayReroll = new SlashCommandBuilder ()
        .setName("reroll")
        .setDescription("choisi un nouveau gagnant du giveaway")
        .addStringOption(option => option
            .setName("message_id")
            .setDescription("id du message a reroll")
            .setRequired(true)
            );
const giveawayEdit = new SlashCommandBuilder ()
    .setName("edit")
    .setDescription("edit un giveaway")
    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("message_id")
        .setDescription("id du giveaway a edit")
        .setRequired(true)
        )
    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("duration")
        .setDescription("ajoute du temps en y/d/h/m/s")
        .setRequired(true)
        )
    .addIntegerOption(option => option
        .setName("winners")
        .setDescription("nouveau nombre de winners")
        .setRequired(true)
        )
    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("prize")
        .setDescription("new prize of the giveaway")
        .setRequired(true)
        );
const giveawayEnd = new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("end")
        .setDescription("end a giveaway")
        .addStringOption(option => option
            .setName("message_id")
            .setDescription("id du giveaway a edit")
            .setRequired(true)
            );
const manager = new GiveawaysManager(Client, {
    storage: './giveaways.json',
    default: {
        botsCanWin: false,
        embedColor: '#FF0000',
        embedColorEnd: '#000000',
        reaction: ''
    }
});

Client.on("ready", async () => {

    Client.application.commands.create(data1);
    Client.application.commands.create(data2);
    Client.guilds.cache.get("971763992152395858").commands.create();
    //supprimer une commande:
    await Client.application.commands.fetch();
    //Client.application.commands.cache.get("id command").delete();
    Client.application.commands.cache.map(command => {
        command.delete();
    });

    console.log("bot opérationnel");
});//log + create command '/'

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content === prefix + "tg") {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#00A2DB")
            .setTitle("ENFIIIIIIIIINNNNNNN!!!!!!!")
            .setURL("https://discord.js.org/")
            .setAuthor("Mighty jo", "https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png", "https://google.com/")
            .setDescription("Y a pas mieux comme bot tema les commandes")
            .setThumbnail("https://images3.alphacoders.com/111/1116286.jpg")
            .addField("**__botto help__**", "Affiche la liste des commandes")
            .addField("**__botto ping__**", "Renvoie pong")
            .addField("**__Quoi ?__**", "renvoie tg toi")
            .setImage("https://images3.alphacoders.com/111/1116286.jpg")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter("Ce bot appartient a jojo92#1263", "https://www.fredzone.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Sukuna-Jujutsu-Kaisen.jpg.webp");
            

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
});//embed

Client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if(message.content === "Quoi ?"){
        message.reply("tg toi");
    }
    /*else if(message.author.id == "220148991663407104"){
        message.reply("tg tu sers a rien");
    }*/
    else if(message.author.id == "687979793052073995" && message.content.startsWith("Salut")){
        message.reply("Bonjour maitre");
    }
});//tg toi

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.content === prefix + "ping"){
        message.reply("botto pong");
    }
    else if(message.content === prefix + "help"){
        message.channel.send("||T'as cru fréro||");
    }
});//ping + help

Client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        if(interaction.commandName === "ping"){
            let user = interaction.options.getUser("utilisateur");

            if (user != undefined){
                interaction.reply("<@" + user.id + ">");
            }
            else {
                interaction.reply("<@220148991663407104>");
            }
        }
        /*else if(interaction.commandName === "help"){
            interaction.reply("pong");
        }*/
    }
});// '/ping' command

Client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    console.log("un membre est arrivé");
    member.roles.add("973997039002193980");

    var canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1000,300);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background = await Canvas.loadImage("./joinimg_demo.png");
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 1000, 300);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(150, 150, 110, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();

    var avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: "png"}));
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 40, 40, 220, 220);
    
    const embedBienvenue = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("**Ho ! Un nouveau membre !**")
        .setDescription(":tada: Bienvenue <@" + member.id + "> :tada:")
        .setImage('attachment://welcome.png');
        
    var attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), "welcome.png");

        
    Client.channels.cache.get("973534330427170826").send({embeds: [embedBienvenue], files: [attachment]});
});//Message arrivée d'un nouveau membre

Client.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => {
    console.log("un membre est parti");
    Client.channels.cache.get("973534330427170826").send("<@" + member.id + "> Dégage batard");
});//message expulsion d'un membre

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.content === "bouton") {
        var row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setCustomId("bouton1")
                .setLabel("appuie batard")
                .setStyle("DANGER")
                .setEmoji("")
            ).addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setLabel("doc discord35")
                .setStyle("LINK")
                .setEmoji("")
                .setURL("https://fr.wikihow.com/cacher-une-%C3%A9rection")
            );
        message.channel.send({content: "message bouton", components: [row]});
    }
});//bouton message avec interaction
Client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isButton()) {
        if(interaction.customId === "bouton1"){
            interaction.reply("pk t'appuyé t'es un chien?");
        }
    }
});//interaction du bouton

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    
    var row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new Discord.MessageSelectMenu()
                .setCustomId("select")
                .setPlaceholder("Select option")
                .addOptions([
                    {
                        label: "premiere option",
                        description: "decrit 1",
                        value: "option1"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "option2",
                        description: "decrit2",
                        value: "2option"
                    }
                ])
        );
    if(message.content === prefix + "menu"){
        message.channel.send({content: "menu de selection", components: [row]});
    }
});//menu de selection
Client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isSelectMenu()){
        if(interaction.customId === "select"){
            console.log(interaction.values);

            if(interaction.values == "option1"){
                interaction.reply({content: "vous avez choisi l'option 1", ephemeral: true});
            }
            else if(interaction.values == "2option"){
                interaction.reply({content: "vous avez choisi l'option 2", ephemeral: true});
            }
        }
    }
});//menu de selection

Client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        if(interaction.commandName === "clear"){
            var number = interaction.options.getInteger("number");

            if(number >= 1 && number <= 100){
                interaction.channel.bulkDelete(number);
                interaction.reply({content: number + "messages supprimés", ephemeral: true});
            }
            else {
                interaction.reply({content: "le nombre de message supprimé doit etre compris entre 1 et 100"});
            }
        }
    }
});//commande  /clear

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.content === "giveaway") {
        var authorId = message.author.id
        var row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setCustomId("bouton2")
                .setLabel("appuie batard")
                .setStyle("DANGER")
                .setEmoji("")
            ).addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setLabel("doc discord35")
                .setStyle("LINK")
                .setEmoji("")
                .setURL("https://fr.wikihow.com/cacher-une-%C3%A9rection")
            );
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
        message.channel.send({content: "message bouton", components: [row]});
    }
});//bouton giveaway
Client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    var row2 = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setCustomId("bouton3")
                .setLabel("appuie batard")
                .setStyle("DANGER")
                .setEmoji("")
            ).addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setLabel("doc discord35")
                .setStyle("LINK")
                .setEmoji("")
                .setURL("https://fr.wikihow.com/cacher-une-%C3%A9rection")
            );
    if(interaction.isButton()) {
        if(interaction.customId === "bouton2"){
            interaction.channel.bulkDelete(1);
            interaction.channel.send({content: "message bouton", components: [row2]});
        }
    }
    if(interaction.isButton()) {
        if(interaction.customId === "bouton3"){
            interaction.channel.bulkDelete(1);
            interaction.channel.send("pk t'appuyé t'es un chien?");
        }
    }
});//interaction du bouton giveaway

Client.giveawaysManager = manager;
Client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    const ms = require("ms");

    if(interaction.isCommand() && interaction.commandName === 'giveaway') {
        const duration = interaction.options.getString('duration');
        const winnerCount = interaction.options.getInteger('winners');
        const prize = interaction.options.getString('prize');
        
        Client.giveawaysManager.start(interaction.channel, {
            duration: ms(duration),
            winnerCount,
            prize
        }).then();
        // And the giveaway has started!
    }
});//create giveaway

Client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {

    if (interaction.isCommand() && interaction.commandName === 'reroll') {
        const messageId = interaction.options.getString('message_id');
        Client.giveawaysManager.reroll(messageId).then(() => {
            interaction.channel.send('Success! Giveaway rerolled!');
        }).catch((err) => {
            interaction.channel.send(`An error has occurred, please check and try again.\n\`${err}\``);
        });
    }
});//reroll

Client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {

    if (interaction.isCommand() && interaction.commandName === 'edit') {
        const ms = require('ms');
        const duration = interaction.options.getString('duration');
        const newWinnerCount = interaction.options.getInteger('winners');
        const newPrize = interaction.options.getString('prize');
        const messageId = interaction.options.getString('message_id');
        Client.giveawaysManager.edit(messageId, {
            addTime: ms(duration),
            newWinnerCount,
            newPrize
        }).then(() => {
            interaction.channel.send('Success! Giveaway updated!');
        }).catch((err) => {
            interaction.channel.send(`An error has occurred, please check and try again.\n\`${err}\``);
        });
    }
});//edit giveaway

Client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {

    if (interaction.isCommand() && interaction.commandName === 'end') {
        const messageId = interaction.options.getString('message_id');
        Client.giveawaysManager.end(messageId).then(() => {
            interaction.channel.send('Success! Giveaway ended!');
        }).catch((err) => {
            interaction.channel.send(`An error has occurred, please check and try again.\n\`${err}\``);
        });
    }
});//end giveaway





Client.login("bot login ");
```

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at transformCommand (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:208:21)
    at create (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:118:30)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\index.js:102:60)
    at emit (node:events:527:28)
    at triggerClientReady (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:17)
    at checkShardsReady (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:367:10)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:189:14)
    at emit (node:events:527:28)
    at checkReady (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:475:12)
    at onPacket (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:447:16)
    at onMessage (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at onMessage (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at emit (node:events:527:28)
    at receiverOnMessage (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1160:20)
    at emit (node:events:527:28)
    at dataMessage (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:528:14)
    at getData (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:446:17)
    at startLoop (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:148:22)
    at _write (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:83:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at socketOnData (c:\Users\hayot\OneDrive - Efrei\KTS Bot\Développement\Jonathan\BOTTOK-KUN\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1254:35)
    at emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
    at callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. It was really the fact that i changed my command i just create them back and it works.

```
  Client.guilds.cache.get("971763992152395858").commands.create(giveawayEdit);
  Client.guilds.cache.get("971763992152395858").commands.create(giveawayEnd);
  Client.guilds.cache.get("971763992152395858").commands.create(giveawayReroll);
  Client.guilds.cache.get("971763992152395858").commands.create(dataGiveaway);
```